# Not accepting keyword argument 'user' in Twitter Tweep API

Tags: python, tweepy

I am having an issue with api.send.direct.message code.
It is throwing an `error; peError: send_direct_message()` got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'. 
I have tried multiple options including screen_name = user.screen_name but no luck.

```
import tweepy
import time

# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("Kr2pjbeG3hDC2", 
"3nunhSaUZ9MeAHpmbEhuEEqSFmj2l2EfaMIzxu9")
auth.set_access_token("107550621-n7OrqgFx", 
"mse3r98sEfziOO95qPCrnD0kUh9lJToxRJ3E0Uzmg")

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

for user in api.followers():
   text="""Hi"""       

   try:
      api.send_direct_message(user=user, text=text) 
      print(user.screen_name)
   except tweepy.TweepError as e:
       print(e.args[0][0]['code'])  # prints 34
      print(e.args[0][0]['message'])
      continue
   except StopIteration:
      break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.send_direct_message), you should specify the recipient's ID:

```
API.send_direct_message(recipient_id, text[, quick_reply_type][, attachment_type][, attachment_media_id])
```

Your code should then look this:

```
import tweepy
import time

# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("Kr2pjbeG3hDC2", 
"3nunhSaUZ9MeAHpmbEhuEEqSFmj2l2EfaMIzxu9")
auth.set_access_token("107550621-n7OrqgFx", 
"mse3r98sEfziOO95qPCrnD0kUh9lJToxRJ3E0Uzmg")

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

for user in api.followers():
   text="""Hi"""       

   try:
      api.send_direct_message(recipient_id=user.id, text=text) 
      print(user.screen_name)
   except tweepy.TweepError as e:
       print(e.args[0][0]['code'])  # prints 34
      print(e.args[0][0]['message'])
      continue
   except StopIteration:
      break
```

Comment: An additional question if that is ok....do you know why the number of users being looped through would stop after about 10?  There are a lot more people following this twitter handle than that.

Comment: According to http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.followers , the `followers()` method only returns 100 results at a time (maybe they changed it to 10 recently). I don't really know though as I never used `tweepy` myself.